# In Linux - How to set permission for folder, which save files for client app call and download file

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

In Linux, How to set permission for folder, which save files for client app call and download file?

> I set : chown -R www-data:www-data ./folder 
>   And: chmod - R 777 ./folder

It's not security, anyone show me how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read, you would need ro perms for www-data on that whole directory, so I'd suggest:

```
chmod -R 400 ./folder
```

For future times:

```
4 - READ
2 - WRITE
1 - EXECUTE
```

Comment: I would like to everyone(anonymous user) can download my file.

Comment: If anonymous users are getting the files through www-data user, then what I posted would work. If each user is accessing the data anonymously, then you would need to give them permissions too, i.e, 644